# Are there caffeine analogs or substituents, and what are they?

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs

I have heard of designer chemists that would take well known drugs, change a hydrogen to a methyl group, and then see what the effect would be in people.

So my question is, what happens in caffeine when these kinds of substitutions are done? What happens if you take the methyl group coming out of one of the nitrogens and make it an Ethyl, or if you change a methyl into a hydrogen? [image: caffeine]

Comment: Did you bother to google this a bit? Wikipedia perhaps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theobromine

Comment: @Karl, how was I to know that Theobromine was the analog? Wikipedia does not have a search-by-structure feature.

Comment: Really. The link in the first line in the wikipedia article about coffeine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there actually a few analogs of  caffeine (**methylxanthines**).

Other than caffeine, the naturally occurring methylxanthines are  **theophylline**,
and **theobromine**:

[image]

*Caffeine* is a widely used CNS stimulant. *Theophylline*
has some medical use as a CNS stimulant, but its CNS stimulant
properties are encountered more often as sometimes
severe, and potentially life-threatening, side effects
of its use in bronchial asthma therapy. *Theobromine* has
very little CNS activity (probably because of poor physicochemical
properties for distribution to the CNS).

Comment: Thanks! This is precisely the info that I was looking for.